# Error deploying to rinkeby

Tags: contract-deployment

I'm trying to deploy my smart contract on rinkeby but getting the following error. Any insight is much appreciated.

```
(node:3817) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): Error: The contract code couldn't be stored, please check your gas limit.
(node:3817) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Contract

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.17;

contract CampaignFactory {

    address[] public deployedCampaigns;

    function createCampaign(string description, uint minimumContribution, string campaignCategory, string endDate) public {
        address newlyCreatedCampaign = new Campaign(description, minimumContribution, campaignCategory, endDate, msg.sender);
        deployedCampaigns.push(newlyCreatedCampaign);
    }

    function getDeployedCampaigns() public view returns (address[]) {
        return deployedCampaigns;
    }
}

contract Campaign {

    struct NewCampaignType {
        string description;
        uint minimumContribution;
        string campaignCategory;
        string endDate;
        address managerAddress;
    }

    struct Request {
        string description;
        uint value;
        address recipient;
        bool complete;
        uint approvalCount;
        mapping(address => bool) approvals;
    }

    mapping(address => NewCampaignType) public campaigns;
    Request[] public requests;
    mapping(address => bool) public approvers;
    uint public approversCount;
    address public currentManagerAddress;

    modifier restricted() {
        require(msg.sender == campaigns[currentManagerAddress].managerAddress);
        _;
    }

    function Campaign(string description, uint minimumContribution, string campaignCategory, string endDate, address managerAddress) public {
        NewCampaignType memory createCampaign = NewCampaignType({
            description: description,
            minimumContribution: minimumContribution,
            campaignCategory: campaignCategory,
            endDate: endDate,
            managerAddress: managerAddress
        });
        campaigns[managerAddress] = createCampaign;
    }

    function contribute() public payable {
        require(msg.value > campaigns[currentManagerAddress].minimumContribution);
        approvers[msg.sender] = true;
        approversCount++;
    }

    function createRequest(string description, uint value, address recipient) public restricted {
        Request memory newRequest = Request({
           description: description,
           value: value,
           recipient: recipient,
           complete: false,
           approvalCount: 0
        });

        requests.push(newRequest);
    }

    function approveRequest(uint index) public {
        Request storage request = requests[index];

        require(approvers[msg.sender]);
        require(!request.approvals[msg.sender]);

        request.approvals[msg.sender] = true;
        request.approvalCount++;
    }

    function finalizeRequest(uint index) public restricted {
        Request storage request = requests[index];

        require(request.approvalCount > (approversCount / 2));
        require(!request.complete);

        request.recipient.transfer(request.value);
        request.complete = true;
    }

    function setCurrentManager(address managerAddress) public {
        currentManagerAddress = managerAddress;
    }

    function getSummary() public view returns (
      uint, uint, uint, uint, address
      ) {
        return (
          campaigns[currentManagerAddress].minimumContribution,
          this.balance,
          requests.length,
          approversCount,
          campaigns[currentManagerAddress].managerAddress
        );
    }

    function getRequestsCount() public view returns (uint) {
        return requests.length;
    }
}
```

deploy script

```
const HDWalletProvider = require('truffle-hdwallet-provider');
const Web3 = require('web3');
const compiledFactory = require('./build/CampaignFactory.json');

const provider = new HDWalletProvider(
  '(metamask 12 word seed phrase)',
  'https://rinkeby.infura.io/4PHzobtaMWvurQjWma6j'
);
const web3 = new Web3(provider);

const deploy = async () => {
  const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();

  console.log('Attempting to deploy from account', accounts[0]);

  const result = await new web3.eth.Contract(
    JSON.parse(compiledFactory.interface)
  )
    .deploy({ data: compiledFactory.bytecode })
    .send({ gas: '1000000', from: accounts[0] });

  console.log('Contract deployed to', result.options.address);
};
deploy();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're supplying 1,000,000 gas, but as the error says, "check your gas limit."

It looks like you need closer to 2,000,000 gas.

Comment: thank you! Just learned about the web3 native getGasPrice and estimateGas functions. Are these the best ways to estimate how much gas is needed per contract?

Comment: `estimateGas` is good. I believe https://ethgasstation.info/ gives better advice in terms of the gas price.

Comment: awesome, always appreciate your input.